# Profiling stored functions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, profiling

Is it possible in Oracle11g to profile stored functions which are invoked in plsql code from within `SELECT ... INTO ...` statement?

For profiling I use `DBMS_HPROF` utility. After a profiling run in `DBMSHP_FUNCTION_INFO` table I can see everything except for functions which were invoked within `SELECT ... INTO ...`.

Answer (score 3):

In 11g2, my HPROF results include lines in package functions that are called as

```
SELECT my_pkg.my_func(x) INTO y FROM dual;
```

Now, I don't see every line -- usually only SQL statements.  For example, I profiled "main_test" in the following package.

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL=0;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE matt_t1 AS
  FUNCTION p (a NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER;

  PROCEDURE main_test;
END matt_t1;

CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE my_num_tab_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY matt_t1 AS
  FUNCTION p (a NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    x   NUMBER := 0;
    t my_num_tab_type;
   BEGIN
     t := new my_num_tab_type();
      for i in 1..10000 loop
          x := ln (x+i);
          t.extend();
         t(i) := x;
     END loop;

     SELECT SUM(column_value) INTO x FROM TABLE(t); 
    RETURN x;
  END p;

  PROCEDURE main_test IS
    x   NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
      x   := matt_t1.p (i);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (x);
    END LOOP;
  END main_test;
END matt_t1;
```

In the HPROF results, I see entries for

```
SELECT SUM(column_value) INTO x FROM TABLE(t);
```

But not, for example,

```
x := ln (x+i);
```

I get the same results whether I call function p as SELECT INTO vs if I just assign a value directly via PL/SQL.  Either way, all the time for the 10,000 natural logarithms is bucketed under the HPROF entry for line

```
FUNCTION p (a NUMBER)
```

I also get the same results if I just profile a call to MATT_T1.P() directly.

So, I think HPROF may have some limitations as to what sorts of PL/SQL lines it can include, but it seems to me that the call method (SELECT..INTO) has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I see all function in DBMSHP_FUNCTION_INFO exept sql function because 
Dbms_hprof dosen't trace sql function (such as ln, nvl... etc.).

```
create or replace function addNum(p1 number,p2 number)  return 
as
begin 
 return p1+p2;
end;

BEGIN
  sys.DBMS_HPROF.START_PROFILING('TMP', 'test.trc');
END;
/

declare 
 n number;
 n2 number;
 n3 number;
BEGIN
  select sum(1),max(1),ln(1) into n,n2,n3 from dual;
  select max(addNum(1,level)) into n from dual connect by level<10;
END;
/

BEGIN
  DBMS_HPROF.STOP_PROFILING;
END;
/
```

So let's into trc file.
`select sum(1) into n from dual;` is marked as `P#C SQL."".""."__static_sql_exec_line6" #6`
 that's mean that static sql has been executed in line 6. 
`select max(addNum(1,level)) into n from dual connect by level<10;` this select starts with `P#C SQL."".""."__static_sql_exec_line7" #7` start in line 6 and next it switches itself to plsql VM to caclucates result of addnum. __plsql_vm and ADDNUM appere 9 times in trc.

```
P#C SQL."".""."__static_sql_exec_line7" #7
P#X 3338
P#C PLSQL."".""."__plsql_vm"  <--switch context
P#X 2
P#C PLSQL."ALUKASIEWICZ"."ADDNUM"::8."ADDNUM"#a7f835561d3611ed #1  <-- execut function
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to see the "return p1+p2;" line in the trace as well.  That is, he wanted it to trace into the addNum() function and report how the time was being spent there.  As I pointed out in my answer, the profile just doesn't contain some PL/SQL lines.  SQL statements always seem to be included, but a simple "P1+P2" is likely to be excluded.  But its inclusion or exclusion seems to have nothing to do with how it is called (either directly or via SELECT AddNum()..).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try enabling profiler inside the stored function? This may create separate trace (different runId ).

Comment: How can it be enabled?

Comment: adding this to function code dbms_hprof.start_profiling( location,filename ,max_depth); and dbms_hprof.stop_profiling .. again this is just to figure out whats happening.. not sure if this can work for ongoing needs of your program.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary.  HPROF *does* include data from inside function calls, even if the function call is called via "SELECT f(x) FROM...".    It's just that some types of PL/SQL lines (e.g., "X := X +1") are not included in HPROF output.  But the call method has nothing to do with what is included or not.  So, starting a separate HPROF run inside each function call is not going to provide any more details that you're already be getting from just the top-level HPROF run.